# -Product of a Hilbert Schmidt and bounded operators is Hilbert-Schmidt

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

For $A\in B(H)$ where H is a separable Hilbert space (so a countable orthonormal basis exists or also known as a maximal orthonormal system) where A is also a Hilbert-Schmidt operator and $B\in B(H)$ (so $B$ does not need to be a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. It is just linear and bounded.) How do I show that $||AB||_{HS}\leq||A||_{HS}||B||_{H}$ and $||BA||_{HS}\leq||A||_{HS}||B||_{H}$ where HS is the Hilbert Schmidt norm and H is just the standard operator norm. I have never been introduced to the trace operator so I can't use that. I can only use the standard Hilbert space inequalities like Cauchy-Schwarz, Parseval's and Bessel's inequality as well as the fact that $\|A\|_H\leq\|A\|_{HS}$ I have not been able to turn the left hand side anywhere close to the right hand side so I'm not sure if there is some trick I'm missing or some inequality I haven't thought of.

Comment: What is your definition of the Hilbert-Schmidt norm?

Comment: The Hilbert schmidt norm is $||A||^2_{HS}=\sum||Ae_i||^2_H$ where ${e_i}$ is an orthonormal basis on the Hilbert Space. I have shown the norm is independent of the choice of basis.

Comment: Great, now if $B$ is bounded, you can estimate $$\Vert BAe_i\Vert_H\leq \Vert B\Vert_H \Vert Ae_i\Vert_H$$ and we are in business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use $\Vert BAe_i\Vert_H\leq \Vert B\Vert_H \Vert Ae_i\Vert_H$ to show $\Vert BA\Vert_{HS}\leq \Vert B\Vert_H \Vert A\Vert_{HS}$. For the other inequality it is useful to first show $\Vert B^*\Vert_H =\Vert B\Vert_H$ and $\Vert A^*\Vert_{HS}=\Vert A\Vert_{HS}.$

Comment: I have already shown that the self adjoint of the HS norm is the same. But do we start the proof of the other inequality $||ABe_i||^2_H$  with $<AB_e_i, AB_e_i>$? and use the adjoints? Or actually, do we start with $||(AB)^*||$

Comment: You say $$\Vert AB\Vert_{HS} = \Vert (AB)^*\Vert_{HS} =\Vert B^* A^*\Vert_{HS} \leq \Vert B^*\Vert_H \Vert A^*\Vert_{HS} =\Vert B\Vert_H \Vert A\Vert_{HS}.$$